# Why chrome.bookmark.getTree() not return value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This function not work correctly. How to make work this function? How to determine execute context this function?

```
function getFolderIdByName() {
    var test;
    chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(bookmarkTreeNodes) {
        test = 123;
    });
    console.log(test); \\ undefined 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getFolderIdByName() {
        var test;
        chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(bookmarkTreeNodes) {
            test = 123;
        });
        console.log(test); \\ undefined 
}
```

is an asynchronous function

So order of execution is

- `var test;`
- `console.log(test);`
- `chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(bookmarkTreeNodes) {
                  test = 123;
  });`

So `console.log(test);` is undefined.

## Reference.

- [Chrome Asynchronous function](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html)

Comment: How I'm can return any value from this function.

Comment: @stevvik: **`return`** as in?